# Bitmaps Being Cached As Bitmaps

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a slideshow type portion of an AIR Mobile for iOS I am working on. There are four pages that the user can scroll through. Each page contains a PNG (as large as 1MB, even after compression) loaded in using the `Bitmap` class and two `TextField`s. As I am scrolling through them (using a custom scroll framework that works without any issues throughout the app), the app is caching each of the PNG images as a Bitmap as they come onto the screen and unloading them when they leave the screen after a period (most likely the next GC, though it seems to be less random than GC).

The act of caching the PNGs is incredibly slow on iOS, especially when it is happening while another action (such as scrolling) is happening. This produces a ~1 sec delay while scrolling, which is obviously unacceptable. Is there a way to either a) prevent the caching or b) keep them cached longer/indefinitely until the images themselves are eligible for GC?

I've triple checked my code and nothing is set to cacheAsBitmap. Additionally, I've been using Adobe Scout to pinpoint what was causing that momentary freeze and it is definitely from caching the images. I've also eliminated any transforms or scales or filters or anything that might turn cacheAsBitmap on in order to operate and the results remain the same.

Comment: Does that scroll framework enforce caching its contents as bitmap? At least during the scrolling.

Comment: @Vesper It did originally, but it was removed because it was too slow on mobile if you did it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that bitmap caching wasn't really the problem afterall. After much more examination, I found that it was actually PNG decompression. Basically, Flash was decompressing PNGs as they were coming on screen (which is even more expensive than caching), adding those to memory, and undoing the process after they had been off the screen for a period of time, meaning I would have to decompress all over again after that period of time for each image.

To get around this, you simply need to access the `BitmapData` object in some way. I used `getPixel( 0, 0 )` in my constructors and the images were decompressed and loaded into BitmapData permanently upon doing so. It will add a bit of time to the startup, but preloading in this fashion results in better performance.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this decompressing on the run (on demand) you can instead request flash to decompress it on load. This will increase the load time but improve the perceived performance of the app since a separate thread takes care of the decompressing. This of course means no jitter or skip when the image hits the screen.

```
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(); 
loaderContext.imageDecodingPolicy = ImageDecodingPolicy.ON_LOAD 
var loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com/myimage.png"), loaderContext);
```

See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS52621785137562065a8e668112d98c8c4df-8000.html

And

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=2931

Embedded images (via code) are not supposed to be compressed, so this problem shouldn't occur with applications that do so. However, if you are like me, and you use the Flash Pro IDE to import PNGs or other bitmap assets, Flash Pro compresses them as JPG by default, using the setting provided by the image itself.

To fix this and avoid these decompression issues, simply go to your Flash Pro asset library, right click on the image you want to change, click on properties and select "lossless / PNG/GIF" as compression. This will increase largely the load time but you will have the much better perceived performance discussed here. This should be done in addition to implementing the code above, or it will make no difference.

In my experience the frame rate average dropped only by one frame per second, but it's much more consistent without any skips or lags which is essential for games.

Since Flash Player will free the decompressed bitmap memory of a BitmapData, here's a solution if decompression still occurs after this: [Keeping Bitmaps Decompressed](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2105).